# Как сделать выход из программы по нажатию одной кнопки. Python

Tags: python

Есть скрипт, в нем есть цикл, как сделать что бы например при нажатии клавиши "P" закрывалась программа?

```
while iTrue == 0:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("p"):
        print('Нажата клавиша выхода из программы: ' + "p")
        iTrue = 1
pyautogui.moveTo(random.randint(285, 289), random.randint(748, 754), 0.5)     #Move to 1st point
pyautogui.dragTo(putRandCordX(), putRandCordY(), TimeToAccept, button='left')
```

Попробовал библиотеку keyboard, но он проверяет нажата ли клавиша слишком редко, пока не завершатся остальные команды в цикле (что бы это сработало клавишу приходиться долбить пока он не поймает её нажатие). Как сделать так что бы он постоянно проверял нажата ли клавиша, не мешая основному циклу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая идея, которая приходит в голову - просто запустить ещё один цикл в отдельном потоке. В таком случае, он совершенно никак не будет зависеть от основного цикла, в котором выполняются команды.

```
from threading import Thread

def exit_check()
    while True:
         if keyboard.is_pressed("p"):
              quit()

thread1 = Thread(target=exit_check)
thread1.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

import sys

sys.exit()

Простой выход))